# how to use toggle slider js

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to  toggle  a value using the slider in html, here is what I've done : 
html file :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script scr="./scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 24px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 100; line-height: 26.4px;">
<div id="myDIV">Hello</div>

        <h2> Testing switch:
                <label class="switch">
                  <input id="status" type="checkbox" checked>
                  <span class="slider round" ></span>
              </h2>


</body>
```

and here the `scripts.js` code I'm using :

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var isChecked = document.getElementById("status");
  if (isChecked.checked ==true) {
    x.innerHTML = "Swapped text!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Hello";
  }
}
```

I don't get what I'm missing, but moving the slide doesn't change the text! any idea how may I solve this? 
thanks in advance !

**update**

the slider is based on [w3-schools Example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch)

Comment: Please provide code that can reproduce the problem, and place it into a snippet.

Comment: You wrapped something in a function but I don't see you calling this function. Either get the code out of the function in the script to have it autorun or call a function from HTML on a certain event like element being loaded, clicked etc..or explicit call function in the script you already have or call it from another script.

What you have is this piece of code and you say, hey I am gonna name that piece of code with this name. And you never call it.

In this specific example you wanna call it on an event that fires when the slider moves, people already wrote how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the switch, nothing happens, because you haven't bound any actions to it. You can add one by binding an `onchange` function:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var isChecked = document.getElementById("status");
  if (isChecked.checked == true) {
    x.innerHTML = "Swapped text!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Hello";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 26.4px;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="myDIV">Hello</div>

  <h2> Testing switch: </h2>
  <label class="switch">
  <input id="status" type="checkbox" onChange="myFunction(this)" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to trigger your function somehow. It doesn't run automatically. The example below fixes that by running `myFunction` when the checkbox changes value using the `onChange` attribute.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var isChecked = document.getElementById("status");
  if (isChecked.checked == true) {
    x.innerHTML = "Swapped text!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Hello";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./layout.css">
  <script scr="./scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 24px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 100; line-height: 26.4px;">
  <div id="myDIV">Hello</div>
  <h2> Testing switch:
    <label class="switch">
    <input id="status" type="checkbox" checked onChange="myFunction(this)">
    <span class="slider round" ></span>
  </h2>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line to your script will make the user input trigger your function.

```
document.getElementById("status").addEventListener("change", myFunction});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the proposed solutions that are correct, this way you don't have to get the elements every time the checkbox changes.

```js
const x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
const checkbox = document.getElementById("status")

checkbox.addEventListener("click", (el) => {
 el.target.checked
    ? x.innerHTML = "Swapped text!"
    : x.innerHTML = "Hello";
})
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">Hello</div>

<h2> Testing switch:
  <label class="switch" />
  <input id="status" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" ></span>
</h2>
```